# Source for story about a boy who asked to be given a scar on his face instead of it being given to his wife

Tags: sources-mekorot, story-identification, hasidic-story, shlomo-carlebach

I remember once hearing a story, the gist of which is:

> Once there was a young girl who was going to be mugged/ accosted by a bandit. A similar aged boy saw what was about to happen, and was able to stop the attack... however the bandit sliced him with a knife across his face which left the boy big scar.
>
> A number of years past and when the boy reached a marriageable age- due to said scar on his face- he had a hard time finding a match. However, one day he found himself on a date with a particular girl... who happened to be the one he had rescued years earlier.

I'm not sure how this next piece of information  came to be known (ie from him or a Rebbe etc) but:

> The boy said that before he was born, in Shamayim he was shown his wife... and saw that it was ***she*** who had a big scar on her face.
>
> > "PLEASE!" the boy pleaded, "I don't want my wife to be hurt and I know how important beauty is to women- let ***me*** be the one who has the scar instead."
>
> Heaven granted his wish and he was given the scar instead of his wife.
>
> After hearing this story the boy and girl married since they knew they were always destined for one another.

I feel like this is a R' [Shlomo Carlebach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Carlebach_(musician)) story but I may be wrong.
**Anyone know the origin of this story and where I might be able to find it?**

Comment: A similar idea was used in a story of how Moses Mendelson won the heart of his wife to be: "[The Best Pickup Line in Jewish History](http://choppingwood.blogspot.com/2010/11/best-pickup-line-in-jewish-history.html)"? (I remember seeing the story in one of the volumes of "מאוצרנו הישן" myself, many years ago.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the exact story you're thinking of, but the first story in *People Speak* ("The Scar") is quite similar. The first few pages of the story are contained in the [Google Books preview](https://books.google.com/books?id=YuNsOj9qpagC&printsec=frontcover&dq=people%20speak%20chaim%20walder&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyoLqR0obkAhWhzlkKHaa4C2QQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=people%20speak%20chaim%20walder&f=false).

Notably, in this version it was not a bandit that attacked the girl but a group of youths, and the weapon was a wooden beam with a nail sticking out rather than a knife.

Unfortunately, the ending of the story is not available there, but from what I recall from reading it years ago they did get married. I do not recall the explanation part as being part of the story, though I may be wrong. If anyone has access to the book, that can be checked out.

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: Not sure how this question is off topic (see sources tag for tons of similar types of questions) but not really something I'm interested in fighting about ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Veha'arev na volume 2 by R' Zilberstein on page 6 has a similar story. R' Chaim Kanievsky gives a brachah to a boy with a scar who cannot convince girls to consider him...the happy ending is similar in detail.